# Mixing python and C++ via std in and std out

Tags: c++, python, stdout, stdin

I have a problem where it is beneficial for me to be able to mix python code and C++ code, and I think that the task is simple enough that it could be done by simply initializing the C++ program from python, and then having the C++ program "wait" for python to give it some input via std in, and then have python "wait" for the C++ program do its computation and return it via std out etc.

I feel like this is either trivial or extremely extremely hard. My main problem is that each time I initialize the C++ code it takes an extremely long time, but that would only need to be done once if I can get this idea implemented. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any reason for not embedding Python in the C++ app?

Comment: Are you using Windows or a Unix based environment?

Comment: Basically, the use case you're describing is a C++ program that acts as a service that accepts one or more "requests" on the standard input and outputs "responses" on the standard output.  The Python script starts this process and translates Python methods to a request and sends it to the C++ program over an anonymous pipe and waits for the response.  Is this correct?

Comment: PabloSantaCruz: Unix

AndréCaron: That's exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the the Submodule library.  You can use Submodule.popen() to create a process from python, using stdin=PIPE and stdout=PIPE. You can then read from the C++ program's stdout and write to its stdin.

Comment: Note that the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) library is not as easy to use as it first looks for this use case (repeated interaction with the same process)  because you can't use `communicate()`.  It's really easy to get a deadlock because anonymous pipes usually have a fixed buffer.  Read the documentation carefully.

Comment: This seemd to work for me. I just alternate between my_proc.stdin.write() and my_proc.stdout.readline() and it seems to get the job done :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like SWIG might be what you're looking for. Use it to generate an extension module for Python, then call your C++ methods from a Python script.